# Empty Forest in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

I was reading the Kruskal's Algorithm application and there was a statement about starting with an empty forest. WHat should I understand from the term 'empty forest'? Does it mean an edge that is not connected or should I think of it as a forest with 1-component?

Comment: I don't know but I can hazard a guess. A graph with no edges (i.e. just isolated vertices) is called an '[empty graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EmptyGraph.html)', and such a graph is a forest, so if we're talking about forests it would make sense to call it an 'empty forest'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually an *empty* object simply doesn't contain any of whatever its highest-level member happens to be. You can talk about forests in terms of nodes and edges, but the conceptual vantage point of a forest is that it contains trees. If it's empty, it just **doesn't contain any trees**.

By extension then, it wouldn't contain any nodes or edges since a forest only contains nodes or edges if its corresponding trees contain those same nodes or edges.

**Extras:** I'm not sure of the author's intention here (whether a forest is defined to be an object containing trees or whether a forest is a graph whose connected components are trees), but in the first interpretation you can run into the interesting state of affairs where a forest has no nodes or edges but is still not empty. How you ask? Simple -- the forest *contains* any positive number of *empty* trees.

Comment: In graph theory "forest" is a pretty standard term and it means a graph whose components are trees, in other words, an acyclic graph. An "empty graph" is a graph with no edges, and an "empty tree" would have one node and no edges. (The so-called "null graph", with no nodes or edges, is not a tree; a tree always has one more node than it has edges. The null graph (a pointless concept if you ask me) is acyclic but not connected.)

Comment: @bof Indeed, most authors don't accept this "null graph" you refer to as a graph at all. (Actually the only time I've seen "null graph" in print has been as an alternative term for "empty graph".)